# Determine ownership of folders in the Java 6.0 cache folder (mac)

Tags: java, macos, caching

how can i determine which application is the owner of which folder inside the Java cache folder?

In this case it's on a Mac inside `~/Library/Cache/Java/6.0/` and there are numbered folders. I suppose the folder numbers relate to applications somehow but I don't know how and where to look them up.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the numbered folders do not correspond to a particular application.  On my system, 10.6, there are precisely 64 folders which is simply how the cache system organizes its contents.  A given application may have cache contents scattered among several different folders, and a given folder may contain contents from multiple applications.